# How do we keep our roasted cashews from smelling bad eventually?

Tags: food-safety, oven, spoilage

We are from a small manufacturing unit and do roasting and packing of cashews. After roasting we pack them in [polypropylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polypropylene) pouches with nitrogen flushing. But after 2-3 months cashews are smelling bad when packets are opened. Kindly help us learn how to overcome this issue.

Comment: How are they being stored for those 2-3 months? In particular, what's the temperature like?

Comment: What do you mean by "smell bad"? Is there another smell you could compare it to ?

Comment: How thick are the polyprop pouches? The thinner ones *will* leak oxygen over a period of weeks. That'll give you rancidity problems over time.

Comment: @ Catija - They are packed in pouches and stored in ambient temperature.. The temp may be 30+ Deg.

Comment: @ Sarumanatee - No. FOUL smell.

Comment: @ Wayfaring Stranger - Its 12 PET 12 MET PET 80 N OCTANE POLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are experiencing rancidity, due to oxygen.

While you have nitrogen flushed the bags at filling time, the bags are not impervious to oxygen diffusion.

A different type of bag (an "oxygen barrier" bag material) or package (glass jar, or metal can) and, in addition, (based on other packaging I have seen) oxygen absorbing packets inside the bag may be required for long shelf life. Either alone would probably extend the shelf-life somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Temperature of the storage area can also be be a significant factor in terms of storage longevity. Nuts will last much longer kept quite cold ( 4 degrees C or less) and even longer when frozen, than they do at room temperatures. Some storage facilities can get very warm at times.